# mysql not starting in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

`sudo systemctl start mysql` command returning the following error

> Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with
>   error code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe"
>   for details.

Comment: Well have you tried `systemctl status mysql.service` and `journalctl -xe`? What did they tell you?

Comment: and what is the error message ?

Comment: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Comment: [ERROR] unknown variable 'key_buffer=16M'

Comment: there were entries for "key_buffer", "myisam-recover" and "thread_concurrency" in my /etc/mysql/my.cnf file which are not compatible with mysql 5.7. Just commented those and its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

there were entries for "key_buffer", "myisam-recover" and "thread_concurrency" in my /etc/mysql/my.cnf file which are not compatible with mysql 5.7. Just commented those and its working as expected. – zakaria